# Script to translate a mySQL datetime column to 'starts in x days/hours'

Tags: php, datetime

I have a MySQL table with events in it. Each event has a datetime column that indicates when it starts.

I'm looking for a way to produce a string similar to this using PHP:

'event X starts in 2 hours'

Should also work for days, weeks and months:

'event X starts in 5 days/weeks/months'

Comment: I honestly don't understand why just not write a simple function to output a string in your format based on just number of seconds. And you get that number from `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_column)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM yourTable WHERE ...` - should be trivial

Comment: @ashein, don't be so condescending. trivial for you, isn't necessarily trivial for me.

Comment: Sorry, tried to expand on it in the answer section. The example data mining for that func is as in my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have some variable with the number of seconds till your date available. My example function is below.

```
<?php

function timeRemaining($total) {
 if (!$total || $total <= 0) return false;
 // define your ranges here (desc order), the keys will go to output.
 $elements = array(
  "years"   => 60*60*24*30*12,
  "months"  => 60*60*24*30,
  "weeks"   => 60*60*24*7,
  "days"    => 60*60*24,
  "hours"   => 60*60,
  "minutes" => 60,
  "seconds" => 1
 );
 // compute in a cycle to compress the code
 $return = array();
 foreach ($elements as $name => $dur) {
  $return[$name] = floor($total / $dur);
  $total -= $return[$name] * $dur;
 }
 // return data in the array form
 return $return;
}

// how much till new year?
echo "<pre>",
print_r(timeRemaining(mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2012)-time()));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Just copy-paste into any php file for testing, as an example it returns the array with years, months etc remaining till new year. You can tailor the output for your needs by feeding the return value to another string-generating function, just don't forget to check the value against `false`, which'll mean the time has passed.

Please note that the months use a simplified 30-days range, and the year here is set to 360 days, not 365.25 as in the real world.

Hope it will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

To use this I first changed the format of the date to:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(date_of, '%d/%m/%Y') as example from tbl
```

The php Function:

```
<?php
    function days_ago($time)
    {
        $today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
        $time_array = explode("/", $time);

       if(count($time_array) < 2)
       {
        $time = "N/A";
       }
       else
       {
         $time =   mktime(0, 0, 0, date($time_array[1]), date($time_array[0]), date($time_array[2]));
         $daysAgo = $today - $time;
         $time = ($daysAgo/86400);    
       }
       return $time;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the following snippet from the [here](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-date-difference.html).

```
<?php
$dateDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
$fullHours = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24))/(60*60));
$fullMinutes = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60))/60);
echo "Differernce is $fullDays days, $fullHours hours and $fullMinutes minutes.";
?>
```

`$date1` would be the database date, `$date2` would be the current date. Does that help?